# How can I download pictures from RESTful server on a client?

Tags: java, android, rest, server, client

I have a big problem on the download from a RESTful server on an Android client. I have a lot of pictures loaded with the Android client and now I would download these with the same client... I would insert the pictures downloaded inside an image view like a gallery but the problem is: how can I download thie pictures and show in my image view... Json? File transfer? Others? I have read a lot of articles and posts but I haven't got any idea on how to solve my problem... Any suggestion are welcome.
Thanks

EDIT:
A solution by coding is required because it is an exercise and I would learn the most by using a code

Comment: can't you just use one the OS solutions available ? Fresco, glide, picasso ?

Comment: Well if downloading the image is not mandatory than I suggest you to just load the picture in the ImageView using the Picassa or any other Image Loading library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can us a library to download de image and insert in ImageView. These libraries are the best known

Glide
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Picasso
http://square.github.io/picasso/

I prefer Glide :)